# Why doesn't \bibliography{myPub} command work in my Latex?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm making my CV, using `LaTeX`. A minimal code can be given as following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\bibliography{myPub.bib}
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

mypub.bib:

```
@article{Cuoco2011,
author = {Cuoco, Domenico and Kaniel, Ron},
doi = {10.1016/j.jfineco.2011.02.012},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Seungkyu Lee/AppData/Local/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Cuoco, Kaniel - 2011 - Equilibrium prices in the presence of delegated portfolio management.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0304405X},
journal = {Journal of Financial Economics},
keywords = {Agency,Asset pricing,Delegation,General equilibrium,Money management},
month = {aug},
number = {2},
pages = {264--296},
publisher = {Elsevier},
title = {{Equilibrium prices in the presence of delegated portfolio management}},
url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0304405X11000456},
volume = {101},
year = {2011}
}
```

When I Bibtex the above file, I got an Exit code (2) error. And the following `.blg` file has been output:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX)
Capacity: max_strings=35307, hash_size=35307, hash_prime=30011
The top-level auxiliary file: cv.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file cv.aux
You've used 0 entries,
            0 wiz_defined-function locations,
            84 strings with 487 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 0 in all, are:
= -- 0
> -- 0
< -- 0
+ -- 0
- -- 0
* -- 0
:= -- 0
add.period$ -- 0
call.type$ -- 0
change.case$ -- 0
chr.to.int$ -- 0
cite$ -- 0
duplicate$ -- 0
empty$ -- 0
format.name$ -- 0
if$ -- 0
int.to.chr$ -- 0
int.to.str$ -- 0
missing$ -- 0
newline$ -- 0
num.names$ -- 0
pop$ -- 0
preamble$ -- 0
purify$ -- 0
quote$ -- 0
skip$ -- 0
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 0
swap$ -- 0
text.length$ -- 0
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 0
type$ -- 0
warning$ -- 0
while$ -- 0
width$ -- 0
write$ -- 0
(There was 1 error message)
```

I have already read several similar questions and corresponding answers, but I have not find a solution. If there is what I am missing, please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have no `\bibliographystyle` command!

Answer (score 3):

There is no `\bibliographystyle{...}` command -- `bibtex` needs a style in order to set the relevant entries.

For this example, I used `\bibliographystyle{alpha}`, but there are different ones, e.g. `unsrt`, `plain`, `abbrv`, `chicago` and `apalike` (and perhaps some more I don't know of ;-))

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\begin{filecontents}{myPub.bib}
@article{Cuoco2011,
author = {Cuoco, Domenico and Kaniel, Ron},
doi = {10.1016/j.jfineco.2011.02.012},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Seungkyu Lee/AppData/Local/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Cuoco, Kaniel - 2011 - Equilibrium prices in the presence of delegated portfolio management.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0304405X},
journal = {Journal of Financial Economics},
keywords = {Agency,Asset pricing,Delegation,General equilibrium,Money management},
month = {aug},
number = {2},
pages = {264--296},
publisher = {Elsevier},
title = {{Equilibrium prices in the presence of delegated portfolio management}},
url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0304405X11000456},
volume = {101},
year = {2011}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{myPub.bib}
\nocite{*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, there is a simple solution! I forgot that argument \bibliographystyle{}. Thank you for your comment.